# SWReveal - how to change the rear VC

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

*This continues from a previous question.*

If I have a TableViewController with the menu options in SWReveal when I click on row 1 how do I get it to present ViewController1, row 2 VC2 etc. The following code (thanks Brandon A) behaves but I don't how I tell it to swap the view controller from the original.

From what I have read you DON'T use segues with SWReveal and must do everything programatically.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    row = indexPath.row
    NSLog("didSelectRowAtIndexPath: %d", row)

    let frontStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main)
    let frontVC = frontStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()

    let rearStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main)
    let rearVC = rearStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()

    // Construct the SWRevealViewController with your view controllers
    if let revealVC = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: rearVC, frontViewController: frontVC) {
        revealVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve // Set segue transition
        present(revealVC, animated: true, completion: nil) // Segue to view controller
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted this by going from Dynamic to Static Cells and forcing the links/segues manually. Pity, would have preferred a coded solution as more adaptable.